# c# sqlconnection to database from project folder

Tags: c#, sql

Hello guys I trying to connect to the database from my project folder here is my code maybe u could help me out?

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = "DataSource=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\bsine_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\Vartotojai.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
cnn.Open();
```

Comment: @ sign before file path "\"!

Comment: @MadMass Wouldn't be enough, but is a component of the solution.

Comment: I need to make my connection string from project folder not the full path

Comment: Can u write full connection string with that?

Answer (score 2):

Your String contains multiple double-quotes and escape characters, i.e. `"` and `\`. You have to make sure that your String value is complete and contained in quotes. You can correct the value as follows:

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\bsine_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\Vartotojai.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

The `@` symbol allows the use of reserved words, and lets you specify a string without the use of escape characters.

Comment: @BensSins - that's because the [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `Data Source`, not `DataSource`. Yes, joyfully, keywords in connection strings can contain spaces and you need to make sure that they match.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a set of inverted commas inside another set, the compiler will throw an error. Try it without the second set of them like this:

```
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
    cnn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\bsine_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\Vartotojai.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    cnn.Open();
```

Comment: As noted above the keyword is "Data Source" not "DataSource". Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

you should use @ Sign before escape characters which begin with "\" sign
as mentioned by @Drew Kennedy

> @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\bsine_000\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\Vartotojai.mdf';Integrated
>   Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

to avoid hard-coding the full path "as you say the database is inside your project folder" you can use the property

> Application.StartupPath

the connection string will be

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\Vartotojai.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
cnn.Open();
```

note: the database file should be inside Debug folder or you should manipulate the Application.StartupPath property to fit your need

Comment: System windows does not contain startupPath
unrecognized escape sequence "\Vartotojai.mdf